# Does chrome have some sort of api that lets you control downloads

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, download, google-chrome-devtools

I am building a chrome extension and would like to be able to have some link between the chrome download manager (ctrl j) and the extension.

Just a simple example the describes what i am trying to accomplish:

An extension that opens a window asking you (are you sure you want to download this file) every time the user downloads a file on chrome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that this is possible, with explicit permissions.

From the chrome dev guide.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads